# How can I hold a specific page after the page is loaded using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler, wait

I made a web-crawler for this page (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) to collect the stock list of each page. First of all, my code starts from manipulating the drop-down menu in the "Search Menu" part, but got some issues on page load and hold during the iteration. What I would like to do is to load a page and hold that page until the crawling action is completed for the page.

Below is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from urllib import parse
from time import sleep

self.link = 'http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I'
self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
self.driver.get(self.link)
self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

def option2_menu_loaded(inDriver):
        path = '//select[@id="level2_no"]'
        return inDriver.find_element_by_xpath(path)

self.wait.until(option2_menu_loaded)

while True:
    try:
        select_option2_values = [
            ('%s' % o.get_attribute('text'), '%s' % o.get_attribute('value'))
            for o
            in Select(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#level2_no")).options
            if o.get_attribute('text') != '세부등급']
    except (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException):
        print("=======Exception Found - Option2 Save=====")
        self.driver.refresh()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(1.5)
        continue
    break

for option2 in select_option2_values:
    self.csv.setCarTitle(ma, mo, de, option1[0], option2[0])

    print(option2[0], option2[1])
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

    while True:
        try:
            Select(self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#level2_no")).select_by_value(option2[1])

        except (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException):
            print("=======Exception Found - Option2 Request=====")
            self.driver.refresh()
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(1.5)
            self.driver.refresh()
            continue
        break
```

I guess some type of "self.wait.until(EC.~)" code after the fifth row,"self.wait.until(option2_menu_loaded)" might help. I tried a lot, but can't find any solution.

Please help me to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"level2_no")))
```

is what you might need if you want to wait for the element to be present before performing any operation on it. Import By at the beginning of the code - `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`.

FYI, I noticed that select tag contains only one option - 세부등급. So `select_option2_values` array will be empty unless you expect `#level2_no` to contain more element in the future.

```
<select id="level2_no" name="level2_no" onmousedown="$('.maker').hide();" onchange="car_depth_step_new(this.value, 4);" style="width:112px" title="세부등급 선택">
<option value="">세부등급</option>
</select>
```